# Ajax request waiting time

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, performance, firebug

I've been working on a project that required me to use Ajax. In the past I have had no problems creating a project with it, but this time every request takes at least 1 second, which is ofcourse way too long.

I can't give you the entire code, but I'll share as much as possible. The requests are as follows:

```
/* *
 * Update the navigation screen
 */
    function UpdateNavigation() {
         $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "application/controllers/LocationController.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data: "action=GetSurroundings",
            success: function(data){
                $("#direction-north").html((typeof data.north != 'undefined' ? data.north : "") + '</br> North');
                $("#direction-west").html((typeof data.west != 'undefined' ? data.west : "") + '</br> West');
                $("#direction-center").html((typeof data.center != 'undefined' ? data.center : "") + '</br> Center');
                $("#direction-east").html((typeof data.east != 'undefined' ? data.east : "") + '</br> East');
                $("#direction-south").html((typeof data.south != 'undefined' ? data.south : "") + '</br> South');
            }
        });
    }

/* *
 * Update the current location
 */
    $('#navigation-list :button').click(function(event) {
        if (event.target.id == "direction-center")
            return;

         $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "application/controllers/LocationController.php",
            data: "action=SetLocation&value=" + event.target.id,
            success: function() {
                UpdateNavigation();
            }
        });
    });
```

As far as I know this could is fine. It might be a good idea to change it a little but it shouldn't cause the delay as far as I know. The LocationController file is pretty big, but it uses a switch for different cases so the actual executed code isn't that big.

Using FireBug I found out that it's waiting for 1.01 seconds for the first request, and 1.00 second for the second request. I did some research and people told me that this might be because the server is too busy to handle your request properly so that's why it's taking so long. But that seems unlikely because the code and database are hosted locally. There shouldn't be a conflict in requests either since they are executed one at a time.

I'm at a loss here. I have no idea how to start debugging this problem. Deleting parts of the code didn't help because it would either stop executing alltogether or just take 1+ second. This leads me to believe the code is not the problem, although I could be wrong.

Any help would be greatly apreciated! If you need more information, please don't hesitate to ask.

Edit: Some more digging around leads me to believe the queries inside the code may be at fault? If so, I'm using the following (pretty ugly) queries:

```
SELECT 
    character_location.block,
    character_location.location
FROM
    character_location
WHERE
    character_location.id = 1
LIMIT
    1



SELECT 
    zones.name,
    zones.location,
    zones.block
FROM
    zones
WHERE
    (
            `zones`.`location` = (".$getBlock['location']." - 1)
        AND
            zones.block = '".$playerBlock."'
    )
OR
    (
            `zones`.`location` = ".$getBlock['location']."
        AND
            zones.block = '".$playerBlock."'
    )
OR
    (
            `zones`.`location` = (".$getBlock['location']." + 1)
        AND
            zones.block = '".$playerBlock."'
    )
OR
    (
            `zones`.`location` = ".$getBlock['location']."
        AND
            zones.block = '".$playerBlockDown."'
    )
OR
    (
            `zones`.`location` = ".$getBlock['location']."
        AND
            zones.block = '".$playerBlockUp."'
    )
LIMIT
    5


UPDATE 
    character_location
SET
    character_location.block = '" . $targetBlock . "',
    `character_location`.`location` = " . $targetLocation . "
WHERE
    character_location.id = 1
```

Guess which one I think might be causing the problem?

Comment: If the request takes 1 second. It's not the JS taking long, but the server PHP.

Comment: I am pretty sure that the problem is server side, to be sure try to output the time before executing any code on the server and right after finishing the work

Comment: I mean outputting from the PHP, not from javascript

Comment: OK, I'll add some stopwatch code in a moment. Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: do you have indexed tables in your DB? and how big is your DB?

Comment: The current database has about 20 tables. My code uses about 3. Each table has a max of 4 columns with only 1 row of dummy data in each of them.

Comment: And all the tables are indexed.

Comment: hmmm... then maybe the problem is in the web server itself, what is the server load?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know how to check that. The server is hosted locally. But the server should be more than capable of handling the load. My other projects are running fine though, no huge delays there.

Comment: what is your OS and what webserver do you use?

Comment: Windows 7 64-Bit, with a Xampp set-up. So Apache I guess.

Comment: check the `httpd.exe` in task manager

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17978/discussion-between-haynar-and-nick)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If you are using PDO for the connection.**

Instead of using `localhost` as the host use `127.0.0.1`

Comment: Awesome, that fixed it! Would you mind sharing with us why that's causing problems? I don't think I've ever not used localhost in my projects and so far it was never a problem.

Comment: Ive had the same issue before i believe its a DNS problem the driver has, Im not 100% sure why it delays exactly 1 second, its most likely doing the lookup then falling back to 127.0.0.1 after it fails.

Comment: Weird, I hope it gets fixed soon.. But either way, it's working now and you've saved me hours of troubleshooting work, haha. Thanks again!

Comment: No probs, glad to have helped